# How can add secret function from string obj witch get from other data file

Tags: python

I want to keep in secret function/method.
This secret function Iv save to *my_file.py*

**my_file.py**

```
def secret(x):
    return x**2
```

Then I’ve crypt file *my_file.py* with function *Crypto.Cipher.AES* and saved to *my_file.d* using pickle.save.

Then I want to use secret function from *my_file.d*:

```
fn='my_file.d'    
with open(fn,'br') as f:
    import pickle
    My_lib=pickle.load(f)
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
My_lib=AES.new(my_key,AES.MODE_EAX,nonce=my_key).decrypt(a)
```

But I can’t import decrypted function, witch now contain from string * My_lib*

How can I **import My_lib** it to use secret function as regular function?

Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit question to be more clear. Which is the binary file, what is `Witch Crypt`, is the `.py` or `.pyc` files from the attached source, what is `pickle`, and what is the purpose of importing these files.

Comment: My thing is, 
1) if I have a file _my_name.py_ or _my_name.pyc_, Im using **import my_name**
2) I have crypt file _my_name.py_ or _my_name.pyc_ witch saved to the pickled file **my_file.d**. 

I seek answer for the second thing. 
The question is, how *"import"* pickled and encrypted object **My_lib** without saving on hard drive. Import memory object.

That is Crypt is vary important for me.

Comment: Please edit question details to get more answers. People will downvote when its unclear :)

Comment: It’s work with exec(), but can use another methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a problem it is solved.
I've using method **exec(t)** , where **t** - string obj, with decrypt secret function.
This function added as method to My_class at /_my.py
Before adding secret function (/secret.py) was encrypted and saved to the binary file (/secret.dat)

---

**/secret.py** *- file with secret function:*

```
def secret(self):
    x=self.x
    return x**2
```

**/to_dat.py** *- encrypt secret.py to secret.dat*

```
def save_secret(fn,key):
    with open(fn+'.py','r') as f:
        a=f.read()
    import pickle
    a=pickle.dumps(a,5)
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
    a=AES.new(key,AES.MODE_EAX,nonce=key).encrypt(a)
    with open(fn+'.dat','bw') as f:
        pickle.dump(a,f,4)

fn='secret' # File name .py and .dat
key=b'059fe945917042000965a2c3adb8dd39' # encrypt/decrypt Key
save_secret(fn,key)
```

**/secret.dat** *- binary encrypt secret.py file*

**/_my.py** *- program using secret function:*

```
fn='secret' # File name .dat
key=b'059fe945917042000965a2c3adb8dd39' # encrypt/decrypt Key

def load_secret(fn,key):
    import pickle
    with open(fn+'.dat','br') as f:
        a=pickle.load(f)
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
    a=AES.new(key,AES.MODE_EAX,nonce=key).decrypt(a)
    return pickle.loads(a)

class My_class:
    def x(self,x):
        self.x=x

    exec(load_secret(fn,key))

mc=My_class()
mc.x(13.2)
print(f'secref function: {mc.secret()}')
print(f'is secret method: {"secret" in dir(mc)}')
print([i for i in dir(mc) if '_' not in i])
```

---

**Results:**

*user@s %* **ls**

```
_my.py      secret.py   to_dat.py
```

*user@s %* **python3 to_dat.py**

user@s % **ls**

```
_my.py      secret.dat  secret.py   to_dat.py
```

*user@s %* **python3 _my.py**

```
secref function: 174.23999999999998
is secret method: True
['secret', 'x']
```